# Search Bar and List View Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm using ListViewBuilder and ListTile to display the data fetched from Firestore.

I want to add search bar at the top of the page and it should filter records in the list view as the user types in the search field.

Is this possible? If yes, how can we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class SelectCity extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SelectCityState createState() => _SelectCityState();
}

class _SelectCityState extends State<SelectCity> {
  List<String> _cityList = [];
  List<String> _newCityList = [];

  void _onItemChanged(String value) {
    setState(() {
      _newCityList = _cityList.where((val) {
        return val.cityName.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase());
      }).toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _cityList = Provider.of<CityData>(context).data;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search City',
                ),
                onChanged: _onItemChanged,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return Container();
                },
                itemCount: _newCityList.length,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```